# Implementing tournament feature on my android game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am new to Google play game service and I want to implement a Real-time multiplayer game for my android app and also set the tournament feature which 8 players will play each other in tournament style with the following idea. Each match will have a constraint that it can be played only for 30 secs to 1 min max after which the winner will be selected and so on till finals.

Please give some ideas that how can i implement tournament feature on my app

Comment: Google Play Games is really limited in what can be done. I think to do a tournament like this, it would have to be single match for the entire tournament and internally you would need to manage the sub-games. You might be better off using a more advanced library.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AppWrap. It is Multiplayer Game Development SDK. You can register multiple user to one room and based on you game logic select the winner.

You can find more help about [AppWarp here](http://appwarp.shephertz.com/game-development-center/android-game-developers-home/).